# If a point is visible on the map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How to know if a point is visible on my map ?

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng)); 
if map.getbounds().contains(point) ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If by visible you are meaning if a point is inside a map's visible area (viewport);

```
// assuming you initialized your map

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));
var currentBounds = map.getBounds() // get bounds of the map object's viewport

if(currentBounds.contains(point)){
    // your location is inside your map object's viewport
}else{
    // your location is out of the bounds of the map's visible viewport
}
```

Comment: I thought that getBounds was not in the V3 ?!

Comment: api reference link is dead now ^^

Comment: @mtness here you are :) -> [ref](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)